# Force GCC to pass arguments in registers

Tags: c++, gcc, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I'm starting to try to mess around with inlining ASM in C++, so I wrote up this little snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int, int, int);


int main(void)
{
    return foo(1,2,3);
}

int foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
    asm volatile("add %1, %0\n\t"
                 "add %2, %0\n\t"
                 "add $0x01, %0":"+r"(a):"r"(b), "r"(c):"cc");
}
```

Which outputs the following assembly code:

```
main:
.LFB969:
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    movl    $3, %r8d
    movl    $2, %edx
    movl    $1, %ecx
    call    _Z3fooiii
```

... stuff not shown...

```
_Z3fooiii:
.LFB970:
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    %ecx, 8(%rsp)
    movl    %edx, 16(%rsp)
    movl    %r8d, 24(%rsp)
    movl    16(%rsp), %edx
    movl    24(%rsp), %ecx
    movl    8(%rsp), %eax
/APP
 # 15 "K:\inline_asm_practice_1.cpp" 1
    add %edx, %eax
    add %ecx, %eax
    add $0x01, %eax
 # 0 "" 2
/NO_APP
    movl    %eax, 8(%rsp)
    ret
```

So I can see where it inputs my code, but what's with the stack manipulations above it? Is there any way I can get rid of them; they seem unnecessary. I should just be able to have

(in main)

```
movl    $3, %r8d
movl    $2, %edx
movl    $1, %ecx
call    _Z3fooiii
```

(in foo)

```
add %edx, %ecx
add %r8d, %eax
add $0x01, %eax
ret
```

How do I make gcc understand that it doesn't need to shove things on the stack and bring them back in a different order? I've fried fastcall and regparam already, and I can't find anything aboout this.

Comment: What happens if you make `foo` an inline function ?

Comment: Strangely enough, nothing changes... which is odd...

Comment: How are you compiling? Is this on windows? 32 bits?

Comment: cygwin, I think I'm using the 64 bit version? I tried it pretty much with every file that ends in gcc/g++ provided in cigwin.

Comment: FYI: if you declare your operands like this: `[a] "+r"(a) : [b] "r"(b), [c] "r"(c)` then you can use names in your asm like this: `add %[b], %[a]`.  Might be a bit easier to read.  Also, this code does not need volatile.  See the docs at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html for a discussion re volatile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to enable optimizations via something like `-O2` in order to get the compiler to try and write better/faster code, instead simpler/easier to debug/understand code.

Comment: When I did this it seemed to copy the code from foo directly to where it is called in main. Is this just because the function is small so it's easily inline-able?

Comment: Although it does work(foo gets turned into `.seh_endprologue
/APP
 # 8 "K:\inline_asm_practice_1.cpp" 1
 add %edx, %ecx
 add %r8d, %ecx
 add $0x01, %ecx
 # 0 "" 2
/NO_APP
 ret`)
Main gets turned into  `movl $1, %eax
 movl $3, %ecx
 movl $2, %edx
/APP` with foo's code copy-pasted below there. Is there a way to prevent this inlining? (This is true for all of the optimize flags)

Comment: If the inlining is a problem, there's always `__attribute__((noinline))`. Obviously you are disabling gcc's optimizations and so will have less efficient code, but if that's what you want...